# VBA - working with get/let for some reason property won't set

Tags: class, vba, excel, properties

Warning: I'm a newbie at VBA.

I have the following class, named `TestClass`:

```
Option Explicit
Private pName As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Name = "test_1"
End Sub
Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property
Public Property Let Name(Value As String)
    pName = Value
End Property
```

I have a subroutine, that I wire up to a button click event, that looks like this:

```
Sub DisplayTestValue()

    Dim testClass As testClass

    With testClass
        MsgBox "default value: " & testClass.Name
    End With

    testClass.Name = "Tom"

    MsgBox "set to (Tom) value: " & testClass.Name

End Sub
```

I then click the button. It calls the subroutine. I get the following error message:

```
Run-time error '91':

Object variable or With block variable not set
```

The debugger stops on the following line of code:

```
MsgBox "default value: " & testClass.Name
```

The debugger tells me that testClass.Name is not set! I am very confused by this because I set a default value of "test_1" to the Name property in the class Initializer.

Can someone please explain to me what I'm not doing correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

I was not using the keyword `New` when instancing an object of my `TestClass`.

Bad:

```
Dim testClass As testClass
```

Good:

```
Dim testClass As New testClass
```

Comment: Or `Dim testClass As testClass` then `Set testClass = New testClass`

Comment: @simpLEMAn has the better way. See http://www.cpearson.com/excel/declaringvariables.aspx and scroll down to "Don't Use Auto-Instancing Variables."

Comment: Thanks @Doug, that's exactly the link I was looking for but could not find it to back my comment.